# In QGIS: buffer a feature to the same layer and keep the original feature

Tags: qgis

In QGIS, is there a way to buffer a feature on the same layer, and also keep the original feature in a single operation.  When you buffer the feature with the "edit features inplace" it modifies the feature, so in effect deleting it. Basically, make a copy of the feature first before executing the buffer command. Not that it is hard to copy the original feature first and then make the buffer operation with "edit feature in place" toggled on, but it seems like there are alot of tools where you would want to have both the original feature and edited feature. So, I'm thinking I'm missing some setting or toggle somewhere. Also, making the buffer to a temporary layer yields to a lot of copy and pasting and deleting temporary layers. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

[Create a model](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/training_manual/processing/modeler_twi.html?highlight=model) using the following steps. You might define an input for the varying buffer sizes so each time you run the model, you can define the buffer size(s).

1. Use [`Geometry by Expression`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisgeometrybyexpression) with an expression like this to create the initial geometry (buffer=0) plus one or more buffers (here: two buffers with distance 1 and 2):

   ```
   collect_geometries (
       array_foreach (
           array(0,1,2),  -- change buffer distance(s) here
           buffer ($geometry, @element)
       )
   )
   ```
2. Run [`Multipart to single parts`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgismultiparttosingleparts) in [Edit features in-place](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=place#the-processing-in-place-layer-modifier) mode.
3. Delete the initial layer.

Comment: This is great, your example is awesome, and allows me to do so much more! It looks like there is the limitation of "Geometry by Expression" can only return one geometry object. I assume there isn't another algorithm that will return multiple features, so you have a clever workaround with collect_geometries. What I would like to do iterate through a range of z values with each buffer. Since only one feature is returned by collect_geometries, I can't store the z in a field. And I'm struggling figuring out how to set the z value of the individual geometries. Thoughts?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. Maybe worth posting as another question with screenshot and sample data?